# Apple Gift Card

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id

I received a $100 apple gift card. I already redeemed it on my account.

Am I able to use this to purchase products on the [Apple Store](http://store.apple.com)?

Comment: Might help clear things up to explain which gift card you have?  Likely iTunes/app store.  This seems to be a point of confusion for some other customers as well, I wonder if apple will eventually find a way to merge those products.

Answer (score 6):

No - cards that you "redeem" are app store cards and only work in the app stores for music, books, movies, apps in the form of digital downloads or rentals.

In summer 2013, Apple has 3 names for gift cards (and many designs for the third name). Shown from http://www.apple.com/gift-cards/ is the following image:

[image]

The former is what most people buy for Apps, Books and Music and can be redeemed through an Apple ID that is paired with either the iTunes store or the Mac App Store. It's the colorful set of cards in the middle above and there are many other designs worldwide.

The left most and right most cards are the iPhone gift card and the traditional silver card with a white Apple logo. Those cards can buy almost anything from the Apple online and physical stores. You need to present that card as part of the purchase an item and it credits you the money towards the purchase as opposed to being redeemed into an account.

Logistically, you could get a store gift card and use it to buy the app store cards, but you can't go the other way and take a balance (or redeemable balance) on the app store cards and convert it back to product through Apple.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apple.com/gift-cards/

Depends which kind of gift card you have. An apple card can.

Comment: Since you cannot redeem either Apple Store gift card, it's almost certain they have an iTunes / App store gift card.

Comment: @bmike good point , didn't catch that.  He just called it the wrong name I suppose.

Comment: People call things all sorts of names. I've heard the Apple store referred to as the iTouch store, the i-store and many other items. Your link was perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what card you have. If it is  a silver apple card with the apple logo in the middle, you can only use it via online or at a real life store. But you can exchange it for an app store, iBook, or iTunes card. Hope I Helped :)

Answer (score -2):

Apple gift card can only be used to purchase on the mac app store, the iphone and ipad app store, the iTunes store and the iBooks store. You cannot use it to buy hardware.

Comment: Apple gift cards can be used for hardware; iTunes and App Store cards cannot. They're different.

Comment: Oups! You're right, I had assume it was an Itunes card because those can be redeem.